# Create table as select with join

Tags: mysql

I need to create table with all un matching id's between table A and table B. Both the tables have some matching fields , but I would need all the columns from table A only

Table A

```
ID NAME address       Phone
12  xyz  some street   1234566
22  xyz  some street   1234566
3  xyz  some street   1234566
```

Table B

```
ID Vendor_NAME address       Phone    email
1  xyz         street       1234566  xyz@gmail.com
2  xyz         street       1234566
3  xyz         street       1234566
```

Resulting table- Table C

```
ID NAME address       Phone
12  xyz  some street   1234566
22  xyz  some street   1234566
```

I am using this query to get all the un-matching values from table A

```
select *  from A left join B on A.ID=B.ID where B.ID is null
```

This gives me all the fields from table A and Table B. How do I create  table C so that it would have only the un-matching values and fields from table A.

Updating a Table B with Table C

Table B

```
ID   Vendor_NAME           street_address Phone    email
1  xyz         street         1234566  xyz@gmail.com
2  xyz         street         1234566
3  xyz         street         1234566
```

Table C

```
ID  NAME  address        Phone
12  xyz   some street    1234566
22  xyz   some street    1234566
```

Update table B

```
ID   Vendor_NAME           street_address Phone    email
1     xyz                   street         1234566  xyz@gmail.com
2     xyz                   street         1234566
3     xyz                   street         1234566
12    xyz                   some street      1234566
22    xyz                   some street      1234566
```

Table B has the same data , but with different column names and would have few extra columns. I would like to insert all the data from table C table B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SELECT * INTO` will help in your case. No need to create the table schema.
It automatically create the table along with give column's data type

```
CREATE Table TableC as SELECT A.* 
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Update answer as per OP's new request:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ID, Vendor_NAME, street_address, Phone, email)
SELECT ID, NAME, address, Phone, NULL
FROM TableC
```

Note: If the `email` is not null column, then instead of `NULL` place two single quotes `''`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  I get  Undeclared variable: tableC . I used create table  tableC as select A.* -----. Thank you

Comment: another question is, how would I update the fields from table C to table B if the columns name are different, Could you give an idea?

Comment: Based on any common Ids from TableC and TableB ?

Comment: Updating my question, Please check it

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: Answer updated. If the `email` is not null column, then instead of `NULL` place two single quotes.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Appreciate your help

Comment: Glad, it helps you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111695/discussion-between-upagna-and-arulkumar).